# Volume of the Region Generated by Three Bounds

Tags: calculus, integration

Determine the volume of the region generated by rotating the region bounded by $y=x$, $x=1$ and $y^2 = 4x$ about the $x$-axis.

The Answer among the choices is $9\pi$.

So I try what's called the "Circular Disk Method" using the following formula:
$V = \pi  \int_{x_1}^{x_2} R^2 dx$

where $R$ is the Radial Distance from $x$-Axis;  the Parabola $y^2 = 4x$ is the higher bound; the Line $y = x$ is the lower bound. Therefore,

$$R = \sqrt{4x} - x$$

Plugin the equations

$$V = \pi  \int_{x_1}^{x_2} R^2 dx$$

and

$$V = \pi \int_{0}^{1}  \big(\sqrt{4x} - x \big)^2  dx,$$

since the bound is $x=1$, I get $0.733\pi$.

Am I doing something wrong? Any Hint? Is it possible answer set is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intersection of x = 1 and $y^2 = 4x$  is (1,2) and the intersection of x= y and $y^2 = 4x$ is (0,0) and (4,4).  The region bounded by all three curves is the parabola $y^2 = 4x$ and x = 1 in the left and $y^2 = 4x$ and x=y in the right and hence the limit 1 to 4.

The mistake that you made  was

$V = \pi * Integral[0,1] * **((\sqrt{4x} - x)^2) * dx**$; Since Bound is x=0 to x = 1  and this limit is wrong too.

$$V = \pi\left(\int_1^4 \left[ (2\sqrt{x})^2 - x^2\right]dx\right)$$

which when you evaluate gets me $9\pi$